# Find $f(r)$ for which $\int \log(x^2 + y^2) f(x^2 + y^2) \ dx$ has simple form

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Consider the following antiderivative
$$
F(x, y) = \int \log (x^2 + y^2) f(x^2 + y^2) dx.
$$
I'm looking for some function $f(r)$ with following properties:

- $f(r)$ is uniformly bounded
- $f(r)$ "screens" the $\log$ term, i.e. $\lim\limits_{r\to +\infty} \log(r)f(r) = 0$
- $F(x, y)$ has simple closed-form.

The better I could find was
$$
\int \frac{\log (x^2 + y^2)}{1 + x^2 + y^2} dx
$$
but the antiderivative is rather ugly.

---

I also tried looking for $F(x,y)$ in the following form
$$
F(x,y) = P(x,y) \log (x^2 + y^2) + Q(x, y).
$$
Omitting the (redundant) constant terms, $P$ and $Q$ are
$$
P(x,y) = \int f(x^2 + y^2) dx\\
Q(x,y) = -\int\frac{2x}{1 + x^2 + y^2} P(x, y) dx
$$

Originally I was interested in some function $g(r)$, satisfying

- $g(r) = \log r + O(1)$ when $r \to 0$
- $\lim\limits_{r\to+\infty}g(r) = 0$
- $\int g(x^2 + y^2) dx$ is simple

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find a simple solution for the second problem:
$$
\int \log \frac{x^2 + y^2}{1 + x^2 + y^2} dx = J(y^2) - J(1 + y^2)\\
J(w^2) = \int \log (x^2 + w^2) dx = x \log (x^2 + w^2) + 2w \arctan \frac{x}{w} - 2x.
$$
Here
$$
g(r) = \log r - \log (1 + r)\\
g(r) = \log r + O(r)\\
g(r) = -\frac{1}{r} + O(r^{-2})
$$